# Query and Sub Query Join in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I want to first join sub category and subling and it should be sub query for join mastercategory

```
$users = DB::table('mastercategory')
->join('subcategory', 'mastercategory.idcategory', '=', 'subcategory.idcategory_mastercategory')
->join('subling', 'subcategory.idsubcategory', '=', 'subling.idsubcategory_subcategory')
->select('mastercategory.*', 'subcategory.*','subling.*')
->get();
```

I want view like this

```
Mobile and Access.
    1. Mobile
      a. IPhone
      b. Nokia
    2. Mobile Cover
```

I tried above query and model but i getting view like this

```
Mobile and Access.
    1. Mobile
      a. IPhone
      b. Nokia
Mobile and Access.              
    2. Mobile Cover
```

Comment: Well your select is ok, you need edit your view (the way you make the category tree). And also much easier it would be, if you use Eloquent relationships

Comment: Have you tried `groupBy('mastercategory.title')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, I have used `joinSub` function instead of `join` it might work according to your needs.

```
$subcategoryWithSubling = DB::table('subcategory')
->join('subling', 'subcategory.idsubcategory', '=', 
'subling.idsubcategory_subcategory')
->select('subcategory.*','subling.*');

$users = DB::table('mastercategory')
->joinSub($subcategoryWithSubling, 'subcategory', function($join) {
    $join->on('mastercategory.idcategory', '=', 
    'subcategory.idcategory_mastercategory')
})->get()
```